# Realm - filtering clustered map view in swift

Tags: realm, predicate

Really loving [the Realm clustered map view tutorial in Swift](https://realm.io/news/building-an-ios-clustered-map-view-in-swift/) but I was wondering if there way a way to easily filter the results using a predicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback! This feature wasn't available in `RealmMapView` at the time of your question, but as of [v1.7](https://github.com/bigfish24/ABFRealmMapView/releases/tag/v1.7), this feature has been added.

The new capabilities work via a property on `ABFRealmMapView`/`RealmMapView` called `basePredicate`. You can set this property with a predicate that filters the Realm objects the map is searching against and it will then be combined with the map's generated bounding box predicate during each refresh.

For example, in the [Swift demo project](https://github.com/bigfish24/ABFRealmMapView/blob/master/SwiftExample/RealmMapViewExample/ViewController.swift) included in the repo, the map is searching for restaurants in San Francisco. By setting the `basePredicate` to this:

```
self.mapView.basePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name BEGINSWITH 'A'")
```

the map will now only show restaurants in San Francisco that start with 'A'.